# Exclude shipping costs from cart's total on Woocommerce cart page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart

Is there any woocommerce hook / method through which I can exclude the shipping cost from the total of the cart?

I searched everywhere but I can't seem to find an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Using this custom function hooked in **`woocommerce_calculate_totals`** action hook, you will exclude the shipping cost from the cart totals *(just the display in cart page)*:

```
// For WooCommerce versions from 2.5.x up to 3+
add_action( 'woocommerce_calculate_totals', 'custom_cart_displayed_totals', 10, 1 );
function custom_cart_displayed_totals( $cart_object ) {

    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    // Only on cart page
    if ( ! WC()->cart->is_empty() && is_cart() ):

        ## Get The shipping totals
        $shipping_tax_amount = $cart_object->shipping_total;
        $shipping_total_excl_tax = $cart_object->shipping_tax_total;

        ## Displayed subtotal
        // $cart_object->subtotal = 0;

        ## Displayed TOTAL
        // $cart_object->total = 0;

        ## Displayed TOTAL
        $cart_object->tax_total -= $shipping_tax_amount;

        ## Displayed TOTAL
        $cart_object->cart_contents_total -= $shipping_total_excl_tax;

    endif;
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

Tested and works…

Comment: is it possible to do the same on checkout page?
For example we show shiiping price (calculated by plugins) only for information for wholesale user role. What should we edit in the code then?

Comment: @kh1 If you want that happen on checkout too, you should remove `&& is_cart()` from the if statement…

Comment: i`ve tried, but no luck. I can manipulate on subtotal but not on total (on checkout page)
Overall i want to see total as subtotal including discounts and excluding shipping
But shipping price should stay visible

Comment: @kh1 This is an old answer and things have changed for WC_Cart Class since WooCommerce 3.2…